# Получение данных из csv в html форму на flask

Tags: html, python, flask, csv

У меня есть файл csv, я могу читать его построчно, и получать только одно значение ячейки в каждый `input` из 5 как на картинке. [5 inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PnxO.png)

Сейчас же у меня есть один `input` и мне нужно добавить в него уже 5 значений ([картинка с 1-м input-ом](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMuNk.png)), как например когда мы добавляем или удаляем теги на форуме чтобы вопрос задать, по такому типу.

Помогите с решением, не знаю где ошибка в коде. Спасибо.

Код [здесь](https://repl.it/repls/NeatTinyPcboard)

Comment: Я не могу понять что вы хотите сделать. Можно поподробнее?

Comment: @user367654, конечно. смотрите. у меня есть `html` форма. Я хочу получать через запятую 5 ячеек из строк моего csv файла, а получаю только одну. Как еще 4 получать?

Comment: Обратите своё внимание на Flask-WTF.

Comment: @user367654 можете какой-то пример скинуть который близок к моему вопросу? Спасибо.

Comment: у вас передается через аякс данные, что ввел человек в форму, потом вы флаксом обрабатываете? тогда наверное, надо отправлять аяксом,то что уже введено и плюсовать к values и через цикл выводить на html

Comment: @JopaBoga можете пожалуйста на моем примере показать? Который день бьюсь с этим вопросом, на форумах не знаю люди как решить это.

Comment: @JopaBoga через аякс не передаётся. Просто прочитываю каждый строчку csv и получаю ее в инпут

Comment: @timur я нем могу код написать, но совет такой, скорее всего передаешь в html файл только одно значение, передавай 1 list и в html jinja2 раскрывай все 5 значений в input

Comment: @JopaBoga да, передаются все 5, но в результате видно только одно, как-будто другие 4 игнорируются

Comment: @JopaBoga, а `disease` откуда?

Comment: @timur, перед тем как рендерить страницу в page_show(), выведи через print values,если там одно значение, значит выше,там где ты считываешь csv, у тебя в list пишется только последние значение из файла или append надо

Comment: @JopaBoga, дело в том что выводил, и выводи все что есть. а уже на рендеринге одно значение только получается. посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131643/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-jquery)

Comment: @timur, https://repl.it/repls/JointLumberingCertifications#main.py добавь сюда свой файл Testing.csv, я там проверю что не так

Comment: @JopaBoga, добавил сюда: https://repl.it/@StackFlow/ComfortableAcademicMedian#main.py

Comment: @timur у тебя проблема в html. <input list="value"> должен иметь такое имя в <datalist id="">, а у тебя идет "val".

Comment: @JopaBoga нужно чтобы  <datalist id=“value”>?

Comment: @JopaBoga, не помогло

Comment: @timur ну смотри, у тебя трабл не в питоне, а тупо в html коде. значит возьми отдельно html код, напиши в нем <input list="value"> и <datalist id=“value”> с тестовыми 5-ю полями, введенными в ручную, и посмотри,заработает или нет. потом удали из этого кода что-то, и запусти итд. у тебя просто не правильно офрмлен html. причем можешь проверять, без flask и python ide, а тупо в html файле и браузере

Comment: как пример, вот это поле вроде пишетс я так  <option value="{{val}}"></option>, а не так  <option value="{{val}}">{{val}}</option>

Comment: @JopaBoga да я уже что только не перепробовал. [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1131643/389005) последнее до чего дошёл. Посмотри пожалуйста

Comment: @timur я в js не шарю толком, сорри

Comment: @JopaBoga, жаль, лан. все равно спасибо!