# Как добавить id формы jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form, select2

Как скрыть 4 поля на странице, но при этом получать их значения в 1 поле, которое внизу?

`пять форм:`

```
<select class="browsers" id="br1" list="browsers" name="browser1" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
      <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
      <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
      <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
      <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
  </select>
<select id="br2" list="browsers" name="browser2" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
      <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
      <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
      <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
      <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
  </select>
<select id="br3" list="browsers" name="browser3" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
      <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
      <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
      <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
      <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
  </select>
<select id="br4" list="browsers" name="browser4" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
      <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
      <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
      <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
      <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
  </select>
<select id="br5" list="browsers" name="browser5" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
      <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
      <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
      <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
      <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
  </select>
```

Сменил эти 5 форм на одну нижнюю и нужно получать остальные 4 значения в эту форму. Я их получаю, но результат некорректный выходит, поэтому как явно их добавлять с помощью `jquery`?

`одна форма:`

```
<select class="browsers" list="browsers" name="browser1" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>
      <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
      <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
      <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
      <option value="Safari">Safari</option>
  </select>
```

`js:`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.browsers').select2();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#br2').hide();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#br3').hide();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#br4').hide();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#br5').hide();
});

</script>
```

Comment: `id=browsers` замените на `class="browsers"` и вызывайте как `$(".browsers")`.select2()` и `name` у элементов формы должен быть либо разный, либо массив. иначе получите только последний элемент при отправке формы

Comment: @teran, сделал, не помогло. я скрыл их по id. посмотрите пожалуйста. обновил код.

Comment: я если честно не особо понимаю что вы сделать хотите.  если элементы на странице не нужны, то удалите их из верстки. Если могут пригодится потенциально, то скройте стилями. не надо для этого js использовать.

Comment: @teran,  я хочу их скрыть. но получать их значения в 1 форму. то есть у меня было 5 форм, с 1-м значением в каждой. а теперь нужно, чтобы была одна форма и в ней было 5 значений.  Можете помочь? который день мучаюсь.